# WordPress is creating nonce as a logged in user but verifying it incorrectly

Tags: ajax, users, admin, validation, nonce

I'm having trouble validating a nonce created with `wp_create_nonce()` inside a hidden input with the name *nonce* in an html form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('action_name'); ?>" />
```

The form submission is done via ajax and validated with `check_ajax_referer('action_name','nonce')`. This always returns `-1`. All REST endpoints have been tested without nonces and work 100% fine.

### The issue seems to stem from wp's user identifcation.

**My debugging so far**

*Nonce creation*
Within *wp-includes/pluggable.php* `wp_create_nonce('action_name')` creates a nonce hashing various variables including the user id and the action.

*Ajax call*
I submit an ajax call which calls `check_ajax_referer('action_name','nonce')`. This in turn calls `wp_verify_nonce($nonce,$action)` which verifies the nonce by hashing the same variables and comparing the two.

*Reverse engineering to locate problem*
My problem is that `wp_create_nonce('action_name')` is being created with the correct user id. However, when I run `check_ajax_referer('action_name','nonce')` which calls `wp_verify_nonce($nonce,$action)` which in turn calls `wp_get_current_user()`; no user is found (user id is 0).

**Evidence the problem is to do with user id**

If I temporarily edit *wp-includes/pluggable.php* to force my user id, the nonce validation works fine. It's as if ajax requests to a known and valid endpoint are being treated as if the user is logged out regardless of whether they are or not.

I'm clearly missing something here, but I have no idea what.

If it helps, this is the REST point registration. As mentioned it works fine without the involvement of a nonce.

```
    register_rest_route(
        'my-namespace', //namespace
        'my-namespace-route-1', //route
        ['methods'=>'POST',
         'callback'=>['Another_Class',//class
             'a_static_function'] //static function
        ] //params
    );
```

Comment: i don't see the code for your AJAX endpooint can you edit your question to include it? Is there a reason you went for the old `admin-ajax.php` api rather than the a newer REST API endpoint via `register_rest_route`?

Comment: I added an example. I think this is the newest API right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because a separate nonce with the action **wp_rest** is not being sent by the server to the client and received back from the client in an HTTP request header called **X-WP-Nonce** with every REST request.

To get this working, you will have to generate a nonce like this:

```
wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')
```

...and provide it to the client making the rest call. Once your client has the nonce value, you need to add it to every REST request e.g.:

```
headers: {
    'X-WP-Nonce': nonce,
}
```

Creating the nonce on the server and accessing it on the client can be done several ways. Using `wp_localize_script()` is the most common and probably best practice for WordPress. `wp_localize_script()` addds a global variable to the client for a script to access. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/.